# why is the only SE site to which I can recommend migration is meta.politics.SE?

Tags: support, migration

When trying to close a question because it "belongs to another SE site", an option menu is presented.  The only option on the menu is meta.politics.SE.

Quite frequently questions from this site are migrated to language/history/law.SE.  Yet those options are not presented.  Currently when people think that those are the appropriate sites, they state so in comments and recommend closing of questions as off-topic.

Why are there no other options in that menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Politics Stack Exchange is still in beta. [Beta sites do not allow to set migration target sites other than their own meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296832/what-are-the-limitations-in-beta).

But moderators can migrate a question to any stack exchange site they want nevertheless. So when you find a question which is off-topic here but would be on-topic on a different stack exchange site, flag it for "in need of moderator intervention" and tell us why it should be migrated in the text box.